# CRLF Injection vulnerability while using slf4j LOGGER in Veracode (CWE 117)

Tags: java, security, veracode, crlf-vulnerability

It's a slf4j logger and i have been trying to log error with 2 messages parameters.

```
catch(ExecutionException executionException) {

LOGGER.error("TimeoutException caught , Error: " + SSG_TIMEOUT.getErrorText() 
       + ". Message: " +executionException.getMessage());    
}
```

`SSG_TIMEOUT.getErrorText()` results to a String `"TimeOut error encountered"`

Things i used

1. Manual sanitize code

   ```
   return entry.replace("\t", "\\t").replace("\b", "\\b").replace("\n", 
       "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r").replace("\f", "\\f").replace("\u0000", 
       "\\0").replace("\\a", "\\a").replace("\\v", "\\v").replace("\\e", 
       "\\e").replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "").replace("'", "\\'").replace("\"", 
       "\\\"").replace("\\", "\\\\");
   ```
2. `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(String errorMessage)`
3. String builder to append string + `escapeJson(StringBuilder.toString())`

Still i see the issue in my veracode report.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First of all first 2 methods of sanitization are correct, its just that there are not supported by Veracode.

Before using a method one should visit *About Supported Cleansing Functions* in
https://help.veracode.com/r/review_cleansers

So, for the above problem **StringUtils.normalizeSpace()** worked.
"StringUtils.escapeJava" could also be used but it seems deprecated

Soln:

```
    catch(ExecutionException executionException) {

    LOGGER.error("TimeoutException caught , Error: " + 
    StringUtils.normalizeSpace(SSG_TIMEOUT.getErrorText() 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @amrit-gopal-singh for providing the list of cleansers Veracode recognized! I spent 3 days digging in their reports, CVWE, OWASP, etc. applying blacklisting, whitelisting, escaping and replacement in vain, until I found your comment and realized veracode recognizes only java.net.URLEncoder.encode() from JSE.